# how can i calculate between 2 date count of solution time in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```sql
SELECT* from ticketOperations  
--this is operations table
INNER JOIN tickets ON tickets.ID = ticketOperations.ticketID, 
--they connect with foreign key
DATEDIFF(DAY,tickets.date, ticketOperations.closingDate) AS SOLUTIONTIME  
--this is calculatefunction 
WHERE tickets.ticketType=0 
--tickettype
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: its not working lol

Comment: because there is syntax error. Can you please share the table structure some sample data and expected output?

Comment: "its not working lol" is not telling us anything (other than you're having fun). If you have an error, please post the error. If the results are not what you expect, post sample data, expected and actual output. Help people help you

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid object name 'DATEDIFF'.
that's my error string

Comment: idk is it possible to use two select in query

Comment: What is `ON tickets.ID = ticketOperations.ticketID, DATEDIFF(DAY,tickets.date, ticketOperations.closingDate) AS SOLUTIONTIME ` trying to achieve? It looks like you're trying to `CROSS JOIN` to a scalar function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing issue as you are using `DATEDIFF` in `ON` clause without any expression or condition.

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 Invalid object name 'DATEDIFF'.
> that's my error string

If you want to know the difference in date then use it in the `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT tickets.*, ticketOperations.*,
       DATEDIFF(DAY,tickets.date, ticketOperations.closingDate) AS SOLUTIONTIME  
  from ticketOperations  
 INNER JOIN tickets ON tickets.ID = ticketOperations.ticketID, 
 WHERE tickets.ticketType=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong. The fixed query below:

```
SELECT 
    tickets.*,
    ticketOperations.*,
    DATEDIFF(DAY,tickets.date, ticketOperations.closingDate) AS SOLUTIONTIME  
FROM ticketOperations  
INNER JOIN tickets ON tickets.ID = ticketOperations.ticketID
WHERE tickets.ticketType=0;
```

[SQL fiddle here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=58b564f1c008edbd46768ada4513f032&php_version=null&sql_version=mssql2017)